# i cannot get the JSON object to the process.php page and unpack it

Tags: php, json, ajax

i read all the posts pertaining to this topic and I tried your solutions but it does not work for me. 
I have a form person.php with five fields from which I collect data in objects literals and store in an array persons.  The problem is I cannot get the array to be sent to the process.php script so as to unpack and store the values in my database. I tried this:

```js
$("#save").click(function(){
  var people = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(persons));
  var my_people = JSON.stringify(people);
  alert(my_people);
  // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "save.php",
   data: my_people, 
   cache: false,
   success: function(data){
  alert(data);
  }
  });
  });
```

i do not also know a lot about ajax that is probably why it does not work. Any help will be highly welcomed

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "save.php",
            data:{param:my_people}, 
            success: function(data){
            //success here means ajax call succeeded, not that the data works
        alert(data);
        }
        });
```

param is the name of your parameter in your server method

Comment: Thanks a million. Please would i be right to use " <?php 
json_decode( my_people, true);?>" to retrieve the data and assign it to table fields in my sql?

Comment: I would go after standard procedures used in CMS systems like Wordpress and see how they do it. I would pop another question on Stack to get some more information because my php is limited.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help